# ProBuilder PivotLocation base center?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to understand why ProBuilder only has FirstVertex or Center as pivot locations. Why not base center?

How does one set the pivot to be base center of a mesh at runtime?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.0/api/UnityEngine.ProBuilder.PivotLocation.html

Comment: We usually cannot answer "why" questions. You'd have to ask the developers of ProBuilder directly why they chose not to implement that particular feature.